# .NET VC++ Redist dependency

Tags: .net, visual-c++

I have an .NET application compiled for AnyCPU that depends on vc++ redist dlls.

It would be difficult for me to have two different builds of .NET app for x86 and x64 platforms so i am trying to investigate if i could load or make my app to pick up the appropriate vc++ dlls automatically.

I am also trying to avoid a scenario when the vc++ redist is not installed on target machine.

So i can have x86 and x64 folder in root of my app to house vc++ dependencies.
The question is how can i make my app to pick them up the way it would if the files would be located in the root folder?

Comment: do you have native x86 and x64 loaded by your .net application?

Comment: i am not sure what you mean.

Comment: There are multiple solutions available for this problem, including one that doesn't require installing anything at all.  You can't get the best answer if you don't show exactly why you have this dependency.

Comment: I guess that your .net application is not directly using vc++ redist functionality but that it is loading another native dll that needs vc++ redist.

Comment: @cristallo yes thats exactly the case.

Comment: you can check Environment.Is64BitProcess and load the right dll accordingly (the vcredist installation is another problem)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757984/dynamically-calling-32-bit-or-64-bit-dll-from-c-sharp-application-using-environm

Comment: so what you say is that calling https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx with the appropriate dll path would allow this ?
What about https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686203(VS.85).aspx this seem to do the same thing?

Comment: it should work but obviously you have to place your dll in two different subfolder

Comment: thats obvious , thanks i will give it a try!

Comment: the installation of the right vcredist is still an open problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check Environment.Is64BitProcess and load the right dll accordingly

the installation of the right vcredist is still an open problem

Comment: See [Deployment in Visual C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293574.aspx)